# Typescript type issue in map function of mixed types react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, union-types

I have defined two types, `Team` and `Position`. They are both part of an array that I iterate over in my react component.

based on the types defined below in my `map` function I am seeing the following error.

Examples of errors I am seeing.

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Position'. [2339]
>
> Property 'position' does not exist on type 'Team'. [2339]

Is it not possible to check that the array contains either type?

My code looks like as follows:

```
type Team = {
   name: string; 
   city: string;
} 

type Position = {
   position: number;
}

const Component = () => {
    const teamsAndPosition = [
       {
        name: 'Arsenal', 
        city: 'London',
       },
      {
        name: 'Everton', 
        city: 'Liverpool',
       },
      { 
         position: 2
      }
    ];

    const [list, setList] = useState<Array<Team | Position >>(teams)
    
    list.map((item: Team | Position) => {
       return item.name ? (
         <div>
           // I am seeing an error for these below
           <p>{item.name}</p>
           <p>{item.city}</p>
         </div>
       ) : (
         <p>{item.position}</p>
       )
    })
}
```

Comment: well if `item` can be `Team` or `Position` should you show the `item.name` and `item.position` alternatively, depding of the type of `item`?

Comment: it is a bit more complicated than what I have posted here. I have dumbed down the example here for the question. Hopefully it still makes sense :-D. Basically I show a different element/component based on the object passed in. but the array can contain either our. Blame the designers :-)

Comment: In both cases, you face a scenario, where property does not exist. You may want to extend your types with `?` optional property, or do a `{item.name ? item.name : ''}`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir has a good working solution for you.  Alternately, if you have the option to change some things around, you could consider making both Team and Position members of a parent class and then call the properties canonically so that there are no requests that can't be fulfilled.  Still, I would add checks to make sure properties are available before trying to access them, else you will run the risk of errors whenever data is incomplete.

Comment: hmmm, obviously I appreciate the help, but I am not sure I really like either of these solutions. The array will always contain one. I will update the question with the array included.

Comment: Updated question@JECarterII

Comment: updated question @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - hopefully it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with a variable that might be one of two (or more) types you can check that a unique property on the object exists before dealing with the object so typescript can deduce what type it is.

Example:

```
interface IObjectYo {
  someProp: number
  same: boolean
}

interface IDifObjYo {
  otherProp: number
  same: boolean
}

function example(someArg: IObjectYo | IDifObjYo) {
  console.log(someArg.someProp) // tsc complains because someProp doesn't belong to IDifObjYo
  if ('someProp' in someArg) {
    console.log(someArg.someProp) // tsc knows it must be type IObjectYo because someProp only belongs to IObjectYo
  } else {
    console.log(someArg.otherProp) // tsc knows this is IDifObjYo because the first condition failed (which means it must be of type IDifObjYo)
  }
  if ('same' in someArg) {
    console.log(someArg.someProp) // make sure the property is indeed unique between the possible types or tsc can't infer
  }
}
```

In your case (and I'm not a React guy) you could do something like this:

```
type Team = {
   name: string;
   city: string
} 

type Position = {
   position: number;
}

const Component = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState<Array<Team | Position >>(teams)

    list.map((item: Team | Position) => {
       return 'name' in item ? (
          <div>
             <p>{item.name}</p>
             <p>{item.city}</p>
          </div>
       ) : (
        <p>{item.position}</p>
       )
    })
}
```

Comment: @peterflanagan, Please try `'name' in item` as your conditional instead of `item.name`. If that doesn't work, are your getting the same error now or a different one?

Comment: that doesn't seem to make as much sense and work with the updated question? I have now included the array

Comment: @peterflanagan, what specifically doesn't make sense? `'name' in item` is checking for the existence of a property, not referring to the property itself; which is why typescript complains.

Comment: this works now, but I don't think it was the way it was at the time :-D

Comment: Glad I could help @peterflanagan. Happy Coding!